# Wordpress random post inside while loop

Tags: wordpress, while-loop

I am using a while loop

while (have_posts()) : the_post();

to get all the post and displaying a page. How to randomise the post. But the problem is, in the page I am working on there is no sign of 'query'. Also I tried to use some solutions mentioned but no result.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the main query with `query_posts($args)` this way:

```
// Alter the query
query_posts( 'orderby=RAND' );

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    // Do your stuff inside the loop

endwhile;

// Reset the query
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this solution but not all the post are displayed.